# When is a type alias of a pointer equivalent to other types in go?

Tags: go, types

I have been trying to figure out why  one particular line will compile, while another won't.. Here's a distilled version:

```
type A *string
type B *string

func TakeStringPointer(a *string) {
    fmt.Println("something: %s\n", *a)
}

func TakeA(a A) {
    fmt.Println("something else: %s\n", *a)
}

func Sample() {
    aa := "asdf"
    var pA A
    var pB B
    var pString *string

    pA = &aa
    pB = &aa
    pString = &aa

    TakeStringPointer(pString)
    TakeStringPointer(pA)
    TakeStringPointer(pB)
    TakeA(pA)
    TakeA(pB) // Does not compile
    TakeA(pString) // Does compile 
}
```

as far as I understand it, `TakeA(pB)` and `TakeA(pString)` should either both work, or both not work...

```
A value x is assignable to a variable of type T if:
x’s type is identical to T.
x’s type V and T have identical underlying types…
```

is in the go spec. For me, I would expect both to compile, as both `A` and `B` have identical underlying types. (Or, neither would, as *string is not the same thing as A, since we have a type declaration).

What's going on here?

Comment: First that's not an alias. It is what it is, which is something that's not useful.

Comment: What is 'it'? And why is it not useful? Does it have to be useful? I am just trying to understand why it works this way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> x’s type V and T have identical underlying types…

You quoted the spec and elided the important part. In full, [that part of the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) reads:

> x's type V and T have identical underlying types **and at least one of V or T is not a defined type.**

What you have is *not* a type alias, it is a defined type. ([Type aliases](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations) are of the form `type A = B`.) Therefore a function that takes the *defined type* `B` cannot take the defined type `A`; it can take `B`, or it can take `B`'s underlying type.

Comment: Ahh, that's exactly what I needed, I should have double checked the _actual_ spec rather than a summary somewhere.

Comment: The Go spec is fantastic. Go is the first language I've worked with where the spec can be read in an hour or two, and it's genuinely worth doing so once you've mastered the basics from the Tour and Effective Go.